# How to connect to simple database table?

Tags: sql-server, database

I don't know much about databases - Sorry if the question seems silly.

I have sql server 2012 on my machine and i create simple database table. 
I want to connect to this database table thru C# code.

So,  I need to know my ConnectionString. 
I don't understand the parameters of the ConnectionString.
I try to google it - but still didn't find any good explanation.

**Anyone can please explain the connectionString fields ?**
How to define the connectionString that i will be able to connect the local database ?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your connection string should be as simple as like below

```
Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=DB_NAME;Integrated Security=True"
```

Where

- `Data Source=.` means local database
- `Initial Catalog=DB_NAME` means the database it will connect to
- `Integrated Security=True` means it will use windows authentication (no user name and password needed; it will use logged in credential)

Take a look [Here](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008/)

(OR)

Search in `Google` with key term `sqlconncectionstring` which will fetch you many help.

**EDIT:**

You are getting exception cause `Initial Catalog=DB_Name\Table_001`. It should be `Initial Catalog=DB_Name` (only database name). Provide the table name in sql query to execute. Check some online tutorial to get more idea on the same.

You use `.` in data source only when you are connecting to local machine database and to the default SQL Server instance. Else if you are using different server and named SQL Server instance then your connection string should look like

```
using(SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection()) 
{ 
sqlConnection.ConnectionString = 
@"Data Source=Actual_server_name\actual_sqlserver_instance_name;
Initial Catalog=actual_database_name_Name;
Integrated Security=True;"; 
sqlConnection.Open(); 
}
```

In case you are using local machine but named SQL Server instance then use

```
Data Source=.\actual_sqlserver_instance_name;
Initial Catalog=Actual_Database_NAME;Integrated Security=True"
```

Comment: Thanks, but is there are more fields that i can use ? any not mandatory fields that can help me ?

Comment: Post your exact connection string; one you are getting exception.

Comment: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

Comment: Not the error; post the connection string you are using?

Comment: using(SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection())
                {
                    sqlConnection.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=DB_Name\Table_001;Integrated Security=True;";

                    sqlConnection.Open();
                }

Answer (score 1):

using System.Data.SqlClient;

Then create a SqlConnection and specifying the connection string.

SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection("user id=username;" + 
                                       "password=password;server=serverurl;" + 
                                       "Trusted_Connection=yes;" + 
                                       "database=database; " + 
                                       "connection timeout=30");

Note: line break in connection string is for formatting purposes only
SqlConnection.ConnectionString

The connection string is simply a compilation of options and values to specify how and what to connect to. Upon investigating the Visual Studio .NET help files I discovered that several fields had multiple names that worked the same, like Password and Pwd work interchangeably.

User ID

The User ID is used when you are using SQL Authentication. In my experience this is ignored when using a Trusted_Connection, or Windows Authentication. If the username is associated with a password Password or Pwd will be used.

"user id=userid;"
Password or Pwd

The password field is to be used with the User ID, it just wouldn't make sense to log in without a username, just a password. Both Password and Pwd are completely interchangeable.

"Password=validpassword;"-or-
"Pwd=validpassword;"
Data Source or Server or Address or Addr or Network Address

Upon looking in the MSDN documentation I found that there are several ways to specify the network address. The documentation mentions no differences between them and they appear to be interchangeable. The address is an valid network address, for brevity I am only using the localhost address in the examples.

"Data Source=localhost;"
-or-
"Server=localhost;"
-or-
"Address=localhost;"-or-"Addr=localhost;"
-or-"Network Address=localhost;"
Integrated Sercurity or Trusted_Connection

Integrated Security and Trusted_Connection are used to specify wheter the connnection is secure, such as Windows Authentication or SSPI. The recognized values are true, false, and sspi. According to the MSDN documentation sspi is equivalent to true. Note: I do not know how SSPI works, or affects the connection.
Connect Timeout or Connection Timeout

These specify the time, in seconds, to wait for the server to respond before generating an error. The default value is 15 (seconds).

"Connect Timeout=10;"-or-
"Connection Timeout=10;"
Initial Catalog or Database

Initial Catalog and Database are simply two ways of selecting the database associated with the connection.

"Inital Catalog=main;"
-or-
"Database=main;"

Comment: what is trusted connection  ?what is the timeout ? timeout of what ? if i don't have password & user name ( using windows default )
 how to set the userName & pass ?

Comment: If you're using "windows default", that's a Trusted Connection. Your string will be like this: `Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Trusted_Connection=True;`. More information [here](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2012/).